# Backgrounding iPhoto sharing via email

Tags: macos, photos.app, sharing

I just found out that when you share a picture in iPhoto via email, the email screen does not go away until the photo has been completely emailed. This means, if its a large photo that I am trying to 'share', depending upon my bandwidth, it takes quite a while to send, during which, I cannot browse any other picture in iPhoto. Is there a way I can background the sharing via email process such that the email screen goes away as soon as I hit the send button and I can proceed on to share other emails. I am fine with the system queuing up the pictures to upload.

The iPhone does it very nicely. Seems like the programmers forgot this backgrounding feature in Mountain Lion...

Answer (score 1):

I usually just switch to Mail, create a new mail there and drag the pictures I want to send from iPhoto into the new mail.

Comment: @ patrix That is perfectly possible and reasonable but I was looking at being able to do it from within iPhoto.